# Cannot change Skype password

Tags: passwords, skype, windows-live-messenger

I wanted to update my personal data on my Skype account, so I clicked the `Manage` button in the Skype UI. That took me to https://secure.skype.com/portal/profile where I could edit the information.

[image]

When I was done editing, I clicked the `Save` button. A password prompt appeared ("Please confirm your password, we're just being extra safe.") I typed my Skype password (which I **know** to be correct, since I always use it to log in), but I got the reply "Oops, that wasn't the right password. Try again."

[image]

I tried about ten times.

Apparently, the password used on the personal info page isn't the same that I use to log in in the Skype UI. Since I have no idea what the latter password might be, I tried to click the `Change password` button on https://secure.skype.com/portal/profile. Then I got to a list of my accounts. This list only contained one item, namely, `Microsoft account`. So I chose to `reset or change [this] password`.

[image]

But then I ended up on an error page, saying that `Messenger has moved to Skype`. I was left with no option to change my password.

[image]

I also found this page: https://login.skype.com/account/password-reset-request

I made a request there by entering my e-mail address. I got a mail with a link, but clicking this only takes me to yet another error message: "Sorry that password token is not recognized, please try entering it again or get another password token."

Entering the code manually doesn't help.

[image]

I suppose I should just give up the idea of updating my personal info, shouldn't I?

Comment: Also, computer software was clearly more 'mature' in the past. Indeed, in the past, a computer application would say 'Incorrect password' like any adult, but now it's 'Oops, that wasn't the right password' like an adolescent.

Comment: Try and just change your Microsoft Account password here:https://account.live.com/Password/Change then use your Microsoft Account ( @outlook.com ) address to log into Skype.

Comment: I also had no problem changing my Skype password: https://secure.skype.com/account/personal/change-password-form if neither of these options work just open a support ticket through Skype's website.